# Cannot write into updmap.cfg?

Tags: fonts, cfg

I'm following the steps outlined [here](https://www.clarkdonley.com/post/2015-03-installing-minionpro-for-latex-on-mac-os-x-yosemite/), I did:

```
mkdir otf
cp /Applications/Adobe\ Reader.app/Contents/Resources/Resource/Font/MinionPro*.otf otf
./scripts/makeall MinionPro
sudo ./scripts/install $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)  
sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c
sudo echo Map MinionPro.map >> $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

And the last line is where I'm getting

```
bash: $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c/updmap.cfg: Permission denied
```

And I don't really know how to proceed. I naively tried creating the file first, but to no avail:

```
$ sudo touch $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c/updmap.cfg
$ sudo echo Map MinionPro.map > $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c/updmap.cfg
bash: $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c/updmap.cfg: Permission denied
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: `sudo echo` doesn’t work, as far as I know, not on all platforms, at least.

Answer (score 4):

When using `sudo some_program >> some_file` only `some_program` is executed with elevated rights. Writing to `some_file` uses normal user rights. The normal solution would be

```
some_program | sudo tee -a some_file
```

where the `tee` program is executed with elevated rights to be able to write to `some_file`. So in your case

```
echo Map MinionPro.map | sudo tee -a $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `sudo echo` didn't work. The trick was to do instead

```
$ echo Map MinionPro.map > updmap.cfg
$ sudo mv updmap.cfg $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c/
```